# Jest-expo test doesn't run

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo

If I follow this readme:
https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/jest-expo

My output when running `npm run test` is this:

```
> apprepo@0.0.0 test C:\Users\[username]\Documents\Projects\[projectname]
> jest

PS C:\Users\[username]\Documents\Projects\[projectname]>
```

It just outputs nothing. I tried with `yarn` as well, but no luck.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and fixed it by changing the "test" scripts section

from:

`"test": "node_modules/.bin/jest"`

to:

`"test": "node ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"`

It seems their GitHub how-to is incorrect.